# Deployed Spring MVC app on Heroku

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-mvc, heroku

I deployed my Spring MVC app on Heroku...But the logs show me the error

`Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block`

I m not getting why this error is occuring as i m new to Postgres..Although my app is working smoothly with postgres locally but on Heroku it throws this error[image]

This is my db config[image]

This is in my Procfile

`web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar --port $PORT target/*.war`

This line in the image

[image]

Comment: Can you show the complete stack trace? What line in your code does it point to? Can you show that code?

Comment: Its pointing towards a line in my Dao class which persists User.I added the image

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10399727/psqlexception-current-transaction-is-aborted-commands-ignored-until-end-of-tra

Comment: And this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672219/hibernate-error-current-transaction-is-aborted-commands-ignored-until-end-of-t

Comment: Actually the problem is that tables are not created by hibernate and i am not getting why the tables are not generated